# NGINX - Add http headers and forward messages to Apache server?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, gps

I am trying to build a fleet management software at the likes of google maps or bing maps and I need the GPS devices to send messages to the server and have the server store them (mySQL).

I have a Apache server (let's say "myserver.com") which only processes/accepts http requests for security reasons. The problem with this configuration is that it does not processes the gps messages because the device does not include http headers on its messages by default.

So, I was thinking on putting a nginx server in between them and make the gps send its messages to the nginx server, which then adds http headers to the original message and forwards it to the Apache server.

I tried finding any good tutorials online but so far haven't been able to find a good one.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on what you mean by 'gps messages'. Is it just http traffic without the appropriate header? If so, you want to use the proxy module. You can find current documentation for it at [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Here is an example:

```
http {
  upstream backend_apache {
    server apache_server1_ip:80;
    server apache_server2_ip:80;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://backend_apache;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It uses GPRS communication, I believe that uses TCP protocol, am I right ?!  But it does NOT uses any http headers or something like that. It's just a "string" with data that will be used to determine some parameters at the server (location of device, signal quality, number of satellites, date etc.) So, well, it's not http traffic. Any suggestions? Thank you.